# extract human readable text from webpage mirror

Tags: c#

What is the best way to extract to text files all the human readable content in a set of websites I have mirrored?

So far I have found BeautifulSoup but I don't know anything about Python.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) provides powerful tools for parsing HTML pages using .NET

Old project page: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/